# Is it worth serving on a program committee if you are going into industry?

Tags: peer-review, industry

I got invited to be on the poster track program committee for a CS conference.  Is it worth accepting the invitation if I am going to become a software engineer when I graduate?

Also, if I review the posters, should I put it on my resume?  (I reviewed posters last year and didn't put it on my resume, but maybe I should.)

Comment: Your question title and description don't match. Program committee is different from review committee.

Comment: The email I got said "Invitation to WWW 2018 Poster Track program committee", and proceeded to outline my responsibilities as a reviewer.

Comment: @Coder In Computer Science the PC is very frequently also the review committee.

Comment: @xLeitix Yes. I agree, as I also belong to the CS cluster. However, in the question it is unclear. Sometimes, reviewers of CS conferences are not part of the program committee. I think OP should edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @xLeitix Sure but "I got invited to review" is a very different thing from "I got invited to be on the program committee". The former sounds like what would be referred to as a sub-reviewer in the CS community, i.e., somebody who was asked by the program committee to review a single submission. This would be analogous to being a referee for a journal, whereas the program committee is analogous to the editorial board).

Comment: I must say, I'm surprised that a conference that claims to have 2500+ attendees would want a student on the program committee.

Comment: Because it is WWW, which is a top notch conference, with a fair bit of industry connected. That actually might change things. You should perhaps include this in the question istelf.

Comment: @DavidRicherby This is about the poster session, though, which makes it at least plausible.

Comment: @user79256 Make sure that this is actually the conference you think it is, because in 2018 WWW actually changed it's name to "The Web Conference" (don't ask): https://www2018.thewebconf.org It's definitely plausible that the invitation text simply has not been updated, but I remember that there also used to be copycat conferences of WWW at some point.

Comment: @xLeitix Also, note that the [programme committee](https://www2018.thewebconf.org/committees/program-committee-members/) for the 2018 conference has already been announced (though maybe that doesn't include the poster track).

Answer (score 2):

You might address this as a 'return on investment' type of problem.

Your investment: you will need to put in some time in reviewing the articles, writing down your findings, perhaps communicating with the rest of the programming committee, etc. How you value this investment depends largely on how much time you have available, how much you enjoy (or dislike) reading the articles on this particular topic, how experienced you are in reviewing, etc.

Return: you might learn something from reading the articles, you might feel that it is benevolent to contribute to science, and it might be relevant for your CV. Again, the value of these depends on your particular situation. Is the conference topic relevant for your career? Do future employers care about these type of activities? Do you care about contributing to science?

The value of the different elements will vary for everybody (depending on their personality and situation), so it is impossible to provide a generic answer.